# Hosted extension installs weeks old code with wrong appid?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to host a chrome extension on my own server. I'm having a really weird issue where every so often I will install the extension by pointing my browser at the .crx and it will install a version of the extension with a different `appid` and which has a codebase which dates back to a couple of weeks ago.

I suspect that I somehow have 2 extension ids in play. One which represents the current codebase and another which entered the mix some time ago.

Is there a way that I can prevent this confusion from occurring?

**Longer Description**
At the very beginning of my extension development process, the version number in my manifest.json was set to "1.0" for some time.

Once development started stabilizing, I reset the version number to "0.0.1" and bumped it from that point whenever I pushed changes.

Whenever I bump the version number, I package the extension and `scp` it to my server. The important parts of that process are below:

Packing the extension:

```
'/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome' --pack-extension=<PATH TO UNPACKED EXTENSION> --pack-extension-key=<GENERATED KEY>
```

The  is the`.pem` private key that was generated by chrome the first time I packed the extension (I think, it is hard to remember since I first packed it some time ago).

Copying the .crx to the server:

```
scp -P <PORT> extension.crx <PATH TO SERVER>
```

Copying the update.xml to the server:

```
scp -P <PORT> update.xml <PATH TO SERVER>
```

The update.xml:

This is a standard update.xml file. The version number and .crx location are as expected. The only potentially interesting thing is the `appid`. I got this `appid` from the Chrome Extensions management page at one point.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<gupdate xmlns="http://www.google.com/update2/response" protocol="2.0">
  <app appid="cdlhmlllfilohhmmpakbcdfaabannega">
    <updatecheck codebase="<EXTENSION CRX LOCATION>" version="0.0.21"/>
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

At this point, I can ssh into my server, unpack the extension there, check the version number and read the codebase and everything will be up-to-date and as expected.

Then, I will point my browser at the `<EXTENSION CRX LOCATION>` and install the extension. The version number will be wrong, the `appid` will not match that in the `update.xml` and the codebase will be from weeks ago.

Comment: Have you already set a fixed extension-ID via the [`manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#key) file? `"key":"cdlhmlllfilohhmmpakbcdfaabannega",`.

Comment: I had it set, but not to the same id string as you have there. Basically I installed my extension and then copied the `"key"` from the `manifest.json` in my chrome directory. This is what [the docs suggest](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#key). I have changed my `"key"` in the manifest to what you suggest now. Unfortunately, this issue appears to be transient so I won't know if it has been fixed right away.

Comment: The IDs in the XML and manifest file have to match.

Comment: I see. Well that's probably the problem all right. If you want to put that into a formal answer I'll accept it if the issue is resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The extension IDs in the XML and [`manifest.json`](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#key) have to be equal.

For future readers: The extension can **only** be packed with the same extension ID when the same `.pem` is used.

For problems regarding the extensionID in the Chrome Web store, see:
    •    [Packaging > Uploading a previously packaged extension to the Chrome Web Store](http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/packaging.html#upload)